# Android Camera: require frontal OR rear camera

Tags: android, google-play, android-camera

My app needs a Camera to work. However, it doesn't matter if it's a rear or frontal camera.

Right now, I have this in my Manifest:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
```

To require a frontal Camera, I know I could also add this:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front"/>
```

But I'd like to support all devices that has EITHER camera. Is there anyway to do this?

For example, I want to support Nexus 7 which has only a frontal camera. But I also want to support devices with rear camera only.

According to some research I've made, such as:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35166

It seems this is not possible.

I think one way to solve this would be to make 2 separate APKs, one with android.hardware.camera and one with android.hardware.camera.front and upload both to Google Play, using its [Multiple APK Support](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html). I haven't tested it yet, though.

**Has anybody found a recommended way to support all devices with a frontal camera, a rear camera or both, but not devices without any cameras?**

Comment: I just want to add +Android Developer confirmed it's not possible (as of JB) to use "use-feature" as I wanted to: https://plus.google.com/u/1/108967384991768947849/posts/iwdKLZvY5cz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several thoughts (no definite answer):

a) I believe you are right that currently there is no good way to require either camera in on APK.

b) If you want, you can remove uses-feature and check for a camera in runtime. It will make user experience worse, but it will work.

c) You can use use required="false" (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html). Hopefully, Google Market prioritize applications using this flag.

c) Side note. As I know most of Android devices have a camera. So, if you go with solution b) or c) only very small user base will notice the difference

Comment: Thank you Victor. I think I'll go with option c) and make required validations at runtime. It seems it's best solution. I'll mark accepted answer in a few hours unless somebody has a better answer.

Answer (score 2):

[This has changed](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#hw-features) since it was answered, you can now add the `uses-feature` to the manifest that requires any camera like this:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.any" android:required="true" />
```

Comment: the problem is the `android.permission.CAMERA` permission implies `uses-feature: name='android.hardware.camera'`, which already includes the `android.hardware.camera.any"` feature. Not sure if this is right, but I ended up specifying `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />` in addition to `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.any" android:required="true" />`

Answer (score 1):

Just to add my 2 cents to this discussion:

I achieved the same result as @Cat described in comment to Juan Cortes.

The way I tested this was using aapt (instructions on testing found in http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#permissions-features ) , and looking for explicit or implicit camera requirements:

No `<uses-feature>` flag, but requiring `camera` permission:
[image]
Observe the `uses-implied-feature`

Using only `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.any" android:required="false" />`:
[image]
Still implying that the app ALWAYS needs a camera.

both `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.any" android:required="false" /><uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />` defined: 
[image]
No more implied features.

Hope this helps somebody profile their own app.