# Cannot find my app in the Google Play on the tablet

Tags: android, google-play, publish, tablet

I developed and published an app.
**build.gradle** has

```
minSdkVersion 11
targetSdkVersion 22
compileSdkVersion 22
```

and **AndroidManifest.xml** has

```html
<supports-screens
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="true"
        />
```

App uses features
[image]

Now, I have a tablet Asus Nexus 7 with Android 5.1. I can launch the app normally on it when debugging. In the developer console it says that Nexus 7 is supported.
[image]

However, I cannot find the app in the Google Play from the tablet. It's invisible for my tablet somehow.

Comment: Can you post your part of the manifest where it says `uses-feature` tag? Also is it the new ASUS Nexus 7 or the old one?

Comment: @ShobhitPuri Updated the question. ASUS Nexus 7 2012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably the problem is your following line:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

the 2012 model only has a front camera and not a rear camera. This tells the play store that a camera is mandatory for the app to run. So it won't show on devices with ONLY front camera. See [Android Camera: require frontal OR rear camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12250944/android-camera-require-frontal-or-rear-camera)

By default `android:required:"true"`. This means that only devices with atleast a rear camera will be able to see this. You can add `android:required="false"` tag which will tell the play store that a camera is not mandatory for it to show on app store.